# How to remove Indexes tab from tables in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, indexing, workbench

How can I remove the indexes from the tables in MySQL Workbench? I am fairly new to MySQL Workbench and am not sure how I can go about doing this. I have searched online but haven't found anything useful. For example; I have look at the MySQL Workbench website and also a answer given on Stack Overflow but both of these use the code side of the MySQL Workbench which I am not sure how to access.

Sorry for the long, lengthy paragraph above, basically what I want to do is remove the indexes from the tables. e.g.

[image]

Remove the yellow highlighted  section.

Also, I know this is going to be off-topic but is it possible to convert these tables/ERD into SQL code? which can be used to create tables in a database.

Comment: You look to be in the modeling interface.  There is a lot more you can do from the SQL editor interface but to be honest, I'm not sure how you switch back and forth or how you export data from the modeling interface.  Might need to look at the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/index.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On MYSQL Workbench tool bar do the following;

Model -> Object Notation -> Workbench (Simplified)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: yes, you can do this using forward engineering:

[image: forward engineering]

The reverse is also possible.